# Issue with editing hover state of KendoUI Button

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, hover

I am attempting to alter the hover functionality of a KendoUI button. The HTML looks like the following:

```
    <div class="div-vertical-delimitor div-float-left"></div>
    <a id="a-draw-point" class="k-button single" title="Point">
        <img id="img-draw-point" src="../Images/DT_DrawPoint.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

The issue is, I'm not seeing a `k-state-hover` class being activated when I hover over the button. However, the button does change when hovering over it.

When hovering over other objects on the page such as toptab links I see the `k-state-hover` being applied when mousing on top of the link.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to CSS and KendoUI.